# How to use insertObjectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

in my app there is are 4 textFields (0,1,2,3). When the user type something and hit the return-Key, i want to save the content of this textField in an array. But i need the right order. For example, when the user first type some information in textField 2 and i call `addObject:` the content is at the index 0. Now i tried to use `inserObjectAtIndex:` but it does not work cause my Array is empty (count = 0). To try `initWithCapacity` is also not a solution. i did'nt try to initialize the Array with empty strings first, but this would be a bad solition. So how can i fix this in a smart way ?? Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

I would use a NSMutableArray that contains four `NSNull` objects and replace the appropriate object when you want to save a string.

Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *dataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[[NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null]]];

// check if object is set
if ([dataSource objectAtIndex:0] != [NSNull null]) {
    // object is set
    textField0.text = [dataSource objectAtIndex:0];
}
else {
    // object is not set
    textField0.text = nil;
}

// set object
[dataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Foobar"];
```

Since you are dealing with NSStrings you could use the empty string `@""` as a placeholder too. This should make everything easier. But a NSArray filled with NSNull objects is the more generic approach.

Comment: OK thank you very much. Finally i had to use replaceObjectAtIndex, cause the insert Method puts in new elements instead.